# Missed country on Global Entry application

Tags: global-entry

So I just filled out my Global Entry on-line application and, after I finished, my wife pointed out that I missed listing Germany as one of the countries visited in the last 5 years. It's too late to go back and change anything.

Does anyone know how strict the DHS is over an error like that? Are they likely to let that pass or have I thrown away my $100 application fee?

Follow up: My wife and I just had our interviews. Everything went very smoothly. In fact, we arrived 20 minutes early (SFO) and they took us immediately. We were both out before the time our interviews were actually scheduled. I was very pleased.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, it did. Originally, it was out in November! I rechecked later and quite a few spots opened up. It looked like they added agents and/or extended hours. I could have gotten an even earlier spot but not with my wife at the same time or at an inconvenient time. As it was, we did 9:30 PM. This was SFO. I don't know if the other offices are as busy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This came up on [Flyertalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/17646625-post15.html) and this helpful answer was provided:

> At your interview, they will give you the chance to update or amend any application information before your fingerprints are submitted for final program approval.

So don't worry. (Also, it is very likely they'd be much more interested in a Syria or a North Korea visit than Germany especially if you've been to the Schengen zone anyways.)

Answer (score 7):

I made a (maybe) more serious omission on my NEXUS application, in that I'm legally a Mexican resident with a nominal second residential address there but I failed to include that address in the 5 year list. At the interview the CBP officer asked about residence in other countries (I don't know whether that's a standard question or he knew something) and, when I told him that, he just added the address in Mexico himself. He didn't seem perturbed by this and I have the NEXUS card.

I also don't think you have much to worry about.